# Insert text below 5 div with an overlay div inside Css Html

Tags: html, css

I want to insert a text below the single people's image.

This is my situation:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
 <div class="layer">
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SILVIA-FAIT-2017_980.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CLAUDIO-ZAMPARELLI-2017_980.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ROBERTA-MAGNANI-2017_980.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/BARBARA-VANNI-2017_980.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-diviso">
   <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SANDRO-CAMPANI-2017_980.jpg">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
 </dvi>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
    background-image: url('http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/a.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(18, 29, 47, 0.96);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 200px 20px 200px 20px;
}

.div-diviso {
    width: 17%;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div-diviso img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.div-diviso .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -o-transform: scale(0.1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.div-diviso:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  visibility: visible;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  transform: border 2.75s;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
 .layer {
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 10px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .layer {
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 5px;
}
}
```

And this is what i want:

[image]

I tried to insert a div with the text after this  but the over effect covers also the written like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a div under each div-diviso and wrap in another div :)

```css
.background {
    background-image: url('http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/a.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(18, 29, 47, 0.96);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 200px 20px 200px 20px;
}

.div-diviso {
    width: 17%;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div-diviso img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.div-diviso .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -o-transform: scale(0.1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.div-diviso:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  visibility: visible;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  transform: border 2.75s;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
 .layer {
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 10px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .layer {
    text-align: center;
}
.div-diviso {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 5px;
}
 .image-description {
   width: 100%;
   color: white;
   text-align:left;
 }
  
  .duties-text {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="layer">
    <div class="div-diviso-container">
      <div class="div-diviso">
        <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SILVIA-FAIT-2017_980.jpg" />
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-description">
        <h2>Silvia Feit</h2>
        <span class="duties-text"> Responsible for some shinanigans</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add text block after overlay

```
<div class="div-diviso">
    <img src="http://77.238.26.244:81/confimi/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SANDRO-CAMPANI-2017_980.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
  <div class="text-block">
      /*here you text*/
  </div>
```